# define many variables from the elements in a list

Tags: python, list, callable

I want to define 500 variables. All the them should be a random number generated from a binomal distribution. Then I would like to show each of them in HTML page.

My code as below:

```
# draw a number from the distribution
def a1s1(self):
    return 3 * np.random.binomial(1, 0.3)

# get rid of the decimal point
def a1s1int(self):
    return int(self.a1s1())

# define 500 variables
number1 = models.FloatField()
number2 = models.FloatField()
....# this should continue in this way until "number500"

# generate a list of 500 random numbers
def drawnumbers(self):
    rnlist = []
    numbers = dict()
    for i in range(1, 500):
        numbers[i] = self.a1s1int()
        rnlist.append(numbers)
    return numbers

# to get each element from the list
number1 = self.drawnumbers[1]
number2 = self.drawnumbers[2]
```

This gave me the error:

```
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

sometimes I got another error "NoneType" is not callable.

Could you please help? I am really new to Python. Many thanks.

Comment: It looks like you're new to Python. Instead of jumping straight to modules like numpy, consider following a tutorial on the basics, such as variables, conditional and looping constructs, data structures like lists and dictionaries, functions, and OOP.

Comment: First, variable `self` on the last two lines of your code has never been defined. You must define it somewhere. On the same lines, you think you call a function, but you do not. Second, do not use name `self`, as it is used as a reference to the object in class methods. Third, why on earth do you want 500 named variables instead of one 500-element list?

Comment: i would like to show each of the element when i click a button on html page. click once, show one. click again, show the second one. I actually think a 500-elelment list is sufficient. I just do not know how to pass the element in the list to the html page

Answer (score 0):

It's better to directly build the list :

```
number=[int(3*np.random.binomial(1,0.3)) for i  in range(500)]
```

You can access them by `number[23]` for exemple.

Comment: I tried your code. it works. but I still have problems to access say number[23]. because if i build the list in your way, one of parameter(the number 3) is created by another functions. so it will be like this:  'number=[int(self.p()*np.random.binomial(1,0.3)) for i  in range(500)]' . p() was defined in class a. Python gave the error that "self is not defined". If i took "self " out, it gave the error that  "p() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'". if i write 'def number(self): return [int(self.p()*np.random.binomial(1,0.3)) for i  in range(500)]' then i can't access number[23].